# Numpy choose without replacement along specific dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Without replacement I'm choosing k elements from a sample n distinct times according to a specified distribution.

The iterative solution is simple:

```
for _ in range(n):
    np.random.choice(a, size=k, replace=False, p=p)
```

I can't set `size=(k, n)` because I would sample without replacement across samples. `a` and `n` are large, I hope for a vectorized solution.

Comment: I don't really understand to question

Comment: Consider `np.random.choice(np.arange(5), size=(3, 5), replace=False)`. This gives the error 'Cannot take a larger sample than population when replace=False'. What I want is to choose 3 values from `range(5)`, 5 times, each time without replacement.

Comment: could you edit with the code that gives you an error ?

Comment: how large are `a` and `n`? are you sure this is not a case of premature optimization?

Comment: If you have large arrays, a loop may in fact be better in order to save on memory usage

Comment: I should have specified that in the end I will operate on the arrays all at once - so I either will join the choices into a single `(k, n)` array or generate it all at once. I asked this question to see if the latter is possible.

Comment: You can preallocate the final result and store each iteration in successive columns.

Comment: @Aaron, he just gave you an example of a and n values 2 comments above your first one.

Comment: @HedwinBonnavaud this was 5 years ago... evidently I commented before fully reading the comments, but like.... clearly it no longer matters.

Answer (score 2):

So the full iterative solution is:

```
In [158]: ll=[]
In [159]: for _ in range(10):
     ...:     ll.append(np.random.choice(5,3)) 
In [160]: ll
Out[160]: 
[array([3, 2, 4]),
 array([1, 1, 3]),
 array([0, 3, 1]),
 ...
 array([0, 3, 0])]
In [161]: np.array(ll)
Out[161]: 
array([[3, 2, 4],
       [1, 1, 3],
       ...
       [3, 0, 1],
       [4, 4, 2],
       [0, 3, 0]])
```

That could be cast as list comprehension: `np.array([np.random.choice(5,3) for _ in range(10)])`.

Or an equivalent where you `A=np.zeros((10,3),int)` and `A[i,:]=np.random...`

In other words you want choices from `range(5)`, but want them to be unique only within rows.

The `np.random.choice` docs suggest an alternative:

```
>>> np.random.choice(5, 3, replace=False)
array([3,1,0])
>>> #This is equivalent to np.random.permutation(np.arange(5))[:3]
```

I'm wondering if I can generate

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       ...
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

and permute values within rows. But with `permute` I can only shuffle all the columns together.  So I'm still stuck with iterating on rows to produce the choice without replacement.

Comment: Nevermind, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279464/sampling-unique-column-indexes-for-each-row-of-a-numpy-array) which you pointed out

Comment: "np.random.choice(5, 3, replace=False) is equivalent to np.random.permutation(np.arange(5))[:3]", is it also equivalent in terms of computation time ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of suggestions.

1. You can preallocate the `(n, k)` output array, then do the choice multiple times:

   ```
   result = np.zeros((n, k), dtype=a.dtype)
   for row in range(n):
       result[row, :] = np.random.choice(a, size=k, replace=False, p=p)
   ```
2. You can precompute the `n * k` selection indices and then apply them to `a` all at once. Since you want to sample the indices without replacement, you will want to use `np.choice` in a loop again:

   ```
   indices = np.concatenate([np.random.choice(a.size, size=k, replace=False, p=p) for _ in range(n)])
   result = a[indices].reshape(n, k)
   ```