# Sampling unique column indexes for each row of a numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random

I want to generate a fixed number of random column indexes (without replacement) for each row of a numpy array.

```
A = np.array([[3, 5, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 3, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 5, 4, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 5, 3]])
```

If I fixed the required column number to 2, I want something like

```
np.array([[1,3],
          [0,4],
          [1,4],
          [2,3]])
```

I am looking for a non-loop Numpy based solution.  I tried with choice, but with the replacement=False I get error

> ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when
>   'replace=False'

Comment: I can't relate your desired result to the original array.  What code produced the `choice` error?  Obviously you  can't choice 10 items without replacement from a population of 6.  Are you trying to select a random 2 items from the 1st row, another random 2 from 2nd, and so on?

Comment: @hpaulj if I do random.randint(A.shape[1], size=(A.shape[0],2)), to select 2 random column indexes for each row I get rows with duplicate entries. and with replace=False, I get error.

Comment: OP wants random indices but it seems that the rows should be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438143/) -

```
def random_unique_indexes_per_row(A, N=2):
    m,n = A.shape
    return np.random.rand(m,n).argsort(1)[:,:N]
```

Sample run -

```
In [146]: A
Out[146]: 
array([[3, 5, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 3, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 5, 4, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 5, 3]])

In [147]: random_unique_indexes_per_row(A, N=2)
Out[147]: 
array([[4, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [2, 0]])
In [148]: random_unique_indexes_per_row(A, N=3)
Out[148]: 
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [3, 4, 2],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [4, 3, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
B = np.random.randint(5, size=(len(A), 2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice()` as following:

```
def random_indices(arr, n):
    x, y = arr.shape
    return np.random.choice(np.arange(y), (x, n))
    # or return np.random.randint(low=0, high=y, size=(x, n))
```

Demo:

```
In [34]: x, y = A.shape

In [35]: np.random.choice(np.arange(y), (x, 2))
Out[35]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```

As an experimental approach here is a way that in 99% of the times will give unique indices:

```
In [60]: def random_ind(arr, n):
    ...:     x, y = arr.shape
    ...:     ind = np.random.randint(low=0, high=y, size=(x * 2, n))
    ...:     _, index = np.unique(ind.dot(np.random.rand(ind.shape[1])), return_index=True)
    ...:     return ind[index][:4]
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [61]: random_ind(A, 2)
Out[61]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 4]])

In [62]: random_ind(A, 2)
Out[62]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1]])

In [64]: random_ind(A, 3)
Out[64]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 1],
       [2, 3, 1]])

In [65]: random_ind(A, 4)
Out[65]: 
array([[0, 4, 0, 3],
       [1, 0, 1, 4],
       [0, 4, 1, 2],
       [3, 0, 1, 0]])
```

This function will return `IndexError` at line `return ind[index][:4]` if there's no 4 unique items in that case you can repeat the function to make sure you'll get the desire result.

Comment: But it seems OP wants `without replacement`.

Comment: @Divakar It seems so, however I gave a solution for unique rows but not unique items in each row 0_0.