# How sample from a linspace without replacement in batches

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'd like to sample `n` random numbers from a `linspace` without replacement and do so in batches. Thus, each sample in the batch should not have repeated numbers, but numbers may repeat across the batch.

The following code shows how I do it by calling `Generator.choice` repeatedly.

```py
import numpy as np
low, high = 0, 10
sample_shape = (3,)
n = 5

rng = np.random.default_rng()  # or previously instantiated RNG
space = np.linspace(start=low, stop=high, num=1000)
samples = np.stack(
    [
        rng.choice(space, size=n, replace=False)
        for _ in range(np.prod(sample_shape, dtype=int))
    ]
)
samples = samples.reshape(sample_shape + (n,))

print(f"samples.shape: {samples.shape}")
print(samples)
```

Current output:

> ```
> samples.shape: (3, 5)
> [[4.15415415 5.56556557 1.38138138 7.78778779 7.03703704]
>  [1.48148148 6.996997   0.91091091 3.28328328 2.93293293]
>  [7.82782783 9.65965966 9.94994995 5.84584585 5.26526527]]
> ```

However, this procedure turns out to be a big bottleneck in my code. Is there a more efficient way of performing this?

Comment: So it is "without replacement" in a single batch but with replacement across batches?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy random choice, replacement only along one axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310009/numpy-random-choice-replacement-only-along-one-axis)

Comment: @ayhan That's correct!

Comment: @Gulzar The logic behind indexing the combinations is solid, however, I think generating all the combinations for bigger `n` might be very slow. I'll try it out to see if it's better than my current implementation.