Efficiently draw random samples without replacement from an array in python
I need to draw random samples without replacement from a 1D NumPy array. However, performance is critical since this operation will be repeated many times.
Here’s the code I’m currently using:
import numpy as np

# Example array
array = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

# Number of samples to draw
num_samples = 3

# Draw samples without replacement
samples = np.random.choice(array, size=num_samples, replace=False)

print("Samples:", samples)

While this works for one sample, it requires a loop to generate multiple samples, and I believe there could be a way to optimize or vectorize this operation to improve performance when sampling multiple times.

Is there a way to vectorize or otherwise optimize this operation?
Would another library (e.g., TensorFlow, PyTorch) provide better
performance for this task?
Are there specific techniques for bulk sampling that avoid looping in
Python?


after your first sample, do you start with the full array again or is the next sample done without replacing the prior sampled items?

After the first sample, I start with the full array again.

Do you need the choice method to draw a fixed set of choices or would it also be ok to draw a larger set in one chunk?

You are not the first to ask for this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002821/numpy-choose-without-replacement-along-specific-dimension

Keep in mind that numpy 'vectorization' just means using compiled functions to work with whole arrays. It moves the loop(s) into compiled code  Your use of 'choice' does that for one num_samples sample   But from one sample to the next you are starting over, right?

@JE_Muc, not sure I understand the question, but num_samples is a variable between 1 and 5. The process in the code snippit should be repeated with different outcomes without the use of a loop.

@hpaulj yes that is the problem, I would like to vectorize multiple outcomes if possible.

But that's the problem, there isn't a np.random function does things in this 'vectorized' way.  The newer Gererator version of choice has more parameters, but doesn't seem to be substantially faster, and doesn't seem to do your desired mix of with/without replacement.

How large are your real array and num_samples, and how many times are you doing it?

Your text and code disagree about "sample"/"samples", please fix.

The code below generates random samples of a list without replacement in a vectorized manner. This solution is particularly useful when the number of simulations is large and the number of samples per simulation is low.
import numpy as np

def draw_random_samples(len_deck, n_simulations, n_cards):
    
    """
    Draw random samples from the deck.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    len_deck : int
        Length of the deck.
    n_simulations : int
        How many combinations of cards are generated. (Doubles could occur.)
    n_cards : int
        How many cards to draw from the deck per simulation. (All cards are unique.)
    
    Returns
    -------
    indices : array-like
        Random indices of the deck. 
    
    """
    
    indices = np.random.randint(0, len_deck, (1, n_simulations))

    for i in range(1, n_cards):
        new_indices = np.random.randint(0, len_deck-i, n_simulations)
        new_indices += np.sum(new_indices >= indices - np.arange(i)[:,None], axis=0)

        indices = np.vstack((indices, new_indices))
        indices = np.sort(indices, axis=0)
    
    return indices.T


First you should use the choice method of a Generator instance, see here. This will increase the performance substantially, according to this post (if this is still up to date):
rng = np.random.default_rng()

samples = rng.choice(array, size=num_samples, replace=False)


Great answer, if I can add something, using a generator also allows you to set the seed: np.random.RandomState(seed=1337).choice( array, size=num_samples, replace=False).

This might do the trick:
import numpy as np

def draw_random_samples(len_deck, n_simulations, n_cards):
    
    values = np.random.random((n_simulations, len_deck))
    indices = np.argpartition(values, n_cards)
    indices = indices[...,:n_cards]
    
    return indices


This operation could be sped up using Numba:
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def draw_random_samples(len_deck, n_simulations, n_cards):

    deck_indices = np.arange(len_deck)
    simulations = [np.random.choice(deck_indices, n_cards, replace=False) 
                   for i in range(n_simulations)]
    
    return simulations


The sample() is an inbuilt method of the random module, which takes the sequence and number of selections as arguments and returns a particular length list of items chosen from the sequence i.e. list, tuple, string or set.
# importing the required module
import random
 
# list of items
List = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40,
        30, 20, 10]
 
# using the sample() method
UpdatedList = random.sample(List, 3)
 
# displaying random selections from 
# the list without repetition
print(List)


Please [edit] your answer to remove the description from the code block. This can be done by unindenting the description.

In quick testing, this use of random is faster than the numpy equivalents.
